# Read only one random row from CSV file and move to another CSV

Tags: python, csv, random

I'm facing a problem in reading random rows from a large csv file and moving it to another CSV file using 0.18.1 pandas and 2.7.10 Python on Windows.

I want to load only the randomly selected rows into the memory and move them to another CSV. I don't want to load the entire content of  first CSV into memory.

This is the code I used:

```
import random

file_size = 100
f = open("customers.csv",'r')
o = open("train_select.csv", 'w')
for i in range(0, 50):
    offset = random.randrange(file_size)
    f.seek(offset)
    f.readline()
    random_line = f.readline()
    o.write(random_line)
```

The current output looks something like this:

```
2;flhxu-name;tum-firstname; 17520;buo-city;1966/04/24;wfyz-street;   96;GA;GEORGIA
1;jwcdf-name;fsj-firstname; 13520;oem-city;1954/02/07;amrb-street; 145;AK;ALASKA
1;jwcdf-name;fsj-firstname; 13520;oem-city;1954/02/07;amrb-street; 145;AK;ALASKA
```

My problems are 2 fold:

1. I want to see the header also in the second csv and not just the rows.
2. A row should be selected by random function only once.

The output should be something like this:

```
id;name;firstname;zip;city;birthdate;street;housenr;stateCode;state
2;flhxu-name;tum-firstname; 17520;buo-city;1966/04/24;wfyz-street;   96;GA;GEORGIA
1;jwcdf-name;fsj-firstname; 13520;oem-city;1954/02/07;amrb-street; 145;AK;ALASKA
```

Comment: You are not selecting a random line.  When you seek to a random number in the file, you're most likely somewhere in the middle of the line.

Comment: @OskarSkog: no: first half-line is dropped. But still this is clumsy. see my answer.

Comment: You say you use pandas but I don't see it here. It seems what you're really trying to  do is to split a dataset (for ml purpose I guess), pandas has df.sample for that. That will solve your 2 problems.

Comment: I think the dataset is _really_ big. Pandas won't probably help

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Yes, you're right, I didn't notice that discarding `f.readline()` line.

Answer (score 1):

You have do simpler than that:

1. first, read the customers file fully, title is a special case, keep it out.
2. shuffle the list of lines (that's what you were looking for)
3. write back title + shuffled lines

code:

```
import random

with open("customers.csv",'r') as f:
    title = f.readline()
    lines = f.readlines()

random.shuffle(lines)

with open("train_select.csv", 'w') as f:
    f.write(title)
    f.writelines(lines)
```

EDIT: if you don't want to hold the whole file in memory, here's an alternative. The only drawback is that you have to read the file once (but not store in memory) to compute line offsets:

```
import random

input_file = "customers.csv"

line_offsets = list()

# just read the title
with open(input_file,'r') as f:
    title = f.readline()
    # store offset of the first
    while True:
        # store offset of the next line start
        line_offsets.append(f.tell())
        line = f.readline()
        if line=="":
            break

    # now shuffle the offsets
    random.shuffle(line_offsets)

    # and write the output file
    with open("train_select.csv", 'w') as fw:
        fw.write(title)
        for offset in line_offsets:
            # seek to a line start
            f.seek(offset)
            fw.write(f.readline())
```

Comment: i'm sorry, i forgot to mention the fact that its a large csv file and so i can't load the entire contents of the csv into memory. i only want to load the random  selected input into the memory

Comment: my alternative solution still needs file to be read once (but not stored). Tell me if it works for you.

Comment: The scripts not running bud. When i execute it, it runs infinitely without showing any results. I'm using pycharm ide.

Comment: it means that the file is really big: it takes a while but will end. Can you try with a smaller file? Or print progression (line count?)

Comment: I tried using a csv with 50 rows. Still the  script executes indefinitely.

Comment: There is something wrong with the code. This is the output i'm getting:

Comment: id;name;firstname;zip;city;birthdate;street;housenr;stateCode;state
city;1974/05/29;wfjn-street; 157;DC;DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA
-city;1978/08/18;nnun-street; 20;OK;OKLAHOMA
ame; 18660;rtw-city;1978/07/16;mzww-street; 179;CA;CALIFORNIA

Comment: whereas original content is something like this:

Comment: id;name;firstname;zip;city;birthdate;street;housenr;stateCode;state;40;zxydx-name;tml-firstname; 14680;jda-city;1974/05/29;wfjn-street; 157;DC;DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA

Comment: What i'm saying is that the script is only reading the second half of the rows i.e., its not reading the values for the following headers within the file: id,name,firstname,zip,city.

Comment: Please compare the first row of values i've provided. Stil thanks, for all your help

Comment: I'm sorry. But this is not the code i want, my friend. I want a code that will only read the randomly selected rows from the input file and only that. Your script is reading the entire file content once, as u earlier mentioned. This is not what i want. Still thank you for your effort.

Comment: It reads the big file once but does not store the data in memory. So it takes time but after that it has the offsets and it can read randomly. I may think of another implementation that would take longer but would not read the file at start. Interested?

Comment: Yes, i would appreciate that

Comment: how's it going with the implementation u told me about? Where u able to implement it? i'm still stuck with the code, bud.

Answer (score 1):

At OP request, and since my 2 previous implementations had to read the input file, here's a more complex implementation where the file is not read in advance.

It uses `bisect` to store the couples of offsets of the lines, and a minimum line len (to be configured) in order to avoid that the random list is too long for nothing.

Basically, the program generates randomly ordered offsets ranging from offset of the second line (title line skipped) to the end of file, by step of minimum_line_len.

For each offset, it checks if line has not already been read (using `bisect`, which is fast but further testing is complex because of the corner cases).
- if not read, skip back to find previous linefeed (that is reading the file, can't do otherwise) write it in the output file, store the start/end offsets in the couple list
- if already read, skip

the code:

```
import random,os,bisect

input_file = "csv2.csv"

input_size = os.path.getsize(input_file)

smallest_line_len = 4

line_offsets = []

# just read the title
with open(input_file,'r') as f, open("train_select.csv", 'w') as fw:
    # read title and write it back
    title = f.readline()
    fw.write(title)

    # generate offset list, starting from current pos to the end of file
    # with a step of min line len to avoid generating too many numbers
    # (this can be 1 but that will take a while)
    offset_list = list(range(f.tell(),input_size,smallest_line_len))
    # shuffle the list at random
    random.shuffle(offset_list)

    # now loop through the offsets
    for offset in offset_list:
        # look if the offset is already contained in the list of sorted tuples
        insertion_point = bisect.bisect(line_offsets,(offset,0))

        if len(line_offsets)>0 and insertion_point == len(line_offsets) and line_offsets[-1][1]>offset:
            # bisect tells to insert at the end: check if within last couple boundary: if so, already processed
            continue
        elif insertion_point < len(line_offsets) and (offset==line_offsets[insertion_point][0] or
               (0 < insertion_point and line_offsets[insertion_point-1][0]<=offset<=line_offsets[insertion_point-1][1])):
            # offset is already known, line has already been processed: skip
            continue
        else:
            # offset is not known: rewind until we meet an end of line
            f.seek(offset)

            while True:
                c=f.read(1)
                if c=="\n":
                    # we found the line terminator of the previous line: OK
                    break
                offset -= 1
                f.seek(offset)
            # now store the current position: start of the current line
            line_start = offset+1
            # now read the line fully
            line = f.readline()
            # now compute line end (approx..)
            line_end = f.tell() - 1
            # and insert the "line" in the sorted list
            line_offsets.insert(insertion_point,(line_start,line_end))
            fw.write(line)
```

- if

Comment: The problem of duplicate rows is still existing i.e., the same row is being moved to the second csv file more than once.

Comment: id;name;firstname;zip;city;birthdate;street;housenr;stateCode;state
1;jwcdf-name;fsj-firstname;13520;oem-city;1954/02/07;amrb-street;145;AK;ALASKA
2;flhxu-name;tum-firstname;17520;buo-city;1966/04/24;wfyz-street;96;GA;GEORGIA
3;xthfg-name;gfe-firstname;12560;vtz-city;1990/01/11;doxx-street;46;NJ;NEW JERSEY
4;ulzrz-name;bnl-firstname;11620;prz-city;1966/08/02;bxqn-street;104;NY;NEW YORK

Comment: This is a part of the input csv (in ur case csv2.csv). When i feed this into ur script, ths is the output i get:

Comment: id;name;firstname;zip;city;birthdate;street;housenr;stateCode;state
4;ulzrz-name;bnl-firstname;11620;prz-city;1966/08/02;bxqn-street;104;NY;NEW YORK
4;ulzrz-name;bnl-firstname;11620;prz-city;1966/08/02;bxqn-street;104;NY;NEW YORK
3;xthfg-name;gfe-firstname;12560;vtz-city;1990/01/11;doxx-street;46;NJ;NEW JERSEY
2;flhxu-name;tum-firstname;17520;buo-city;1966/04/24;wfyz-street;96;GA;GEORGIA
1;jwcdf-name;fsj-firstname;13520;oem-city;1954/02/07;amrb-street;145;AK;ALASKA

Comment: As u can see, same row is being read into the output csv file namely train_select.csv

Comment: I meant same row from input file is being read and moved to the output file more than once.

Comment: Can u help me with this, bud?